# What could cause issues migrating a Python plugin to another Windows version?

Tags: qgis, windows

I am developing a plugin in my laptop and the plugin runs well. So, I installed the same version in other computer and the plugin doesn't run well. Sometimes I develop the code in laptop, sometimes in the other computer. The same language (python), the same version. The windows is different, one is vista and the other is windows 7. The difference can be here?

Can someaone explain me why?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run well"? You need to be much more specific.

Comment: The code that I am developing in my laptop doesn´t run in the other computer with the same version of QGIS. When I copy the plugin to the other computer, it doesn't run.

Answer (score 1):

The QGIS API is same, no matter which Windows version you are running. Did you install QGIS from the same source (OSGeo4W or stand-alone installer) on both machines? There might be some differences in the Python you've installed.

Comment: I think I install QGIS from the same source (OSGEO4W). I try uninstall and install again but some tools of my plugin doesn't run in the second computer.